# Salesforce Tooling API

Tags: tooling-api

I am using salesforce's tooling API to get metadata changes for CustomField objects where were modified after a certain date. I am using the following code which is written in JAVA.

Q.> How to write a greater than "LastModifiedDate" criteria ?

```
    private static final String created_date_compared = "2016-02-01T00:00:00.000+0000";
String restURL;
        restURL = "/tooling/query/?q=Select+Id,DeveloperName,NamespacePrefix+From+CustomField+Where+LastModifiedDate+>+="+ created_date_compared;
```

I am getting the following error. If I remove the > sign the query works fine.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 144: https://na9.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+Id,DeveloperName,NamespacePrefix+From+CustomField+Where+LastModifiedDate+>+=2016-02-01T00:00:00.000+0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example query has few confusing (for API) places, e.g.

> LastModifiedDate+>+=

API reads this as "LastModifiedDate > =", note the space between ">" and "="

> 2016-02-01T00:00:00.000+0000

API reads this as

> 2016-02-01T00:00:00.000 0000

again, note the space before last "0000"

The simplest way is to write you query as normal and then URL Encode it, for example using http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Original query

> Select Id,DeveloperName,NamespacePrefix From CustomField Where LastModifiedDate >=2016-02-01T00:00:00.000+0000

after using URL encoder becomes this

> Select%20Id%2CDeveloperName%2CNamespacePrefix%20From%20CustomField%20Where%20LastModifiedDate%20%3E%3D2016-02-01T00%3A00%3A00.000%2B0000

Since you mentioned java, your case may look something like this:

```
String query = java.net.URLEncoder.encode("Select Id,DeveloperName,NamespacePrefix From CustomField Where LastModifiedDate >="+ created_date_compared);
```

which produces the same result as online encoder above.

and then full API url becomes this:

```
String restURL = "/tooling/query/?q=" + query;
```

which results in this

> /services/data/v36.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+Id%2CDeveloperName%2CNamespacePrefix+From+CustomField+Where+LastModifiedDate+%3E%3D2016-02-01T00%3A00%3A00.000%2B0000

Comment: Thank you, I used your advice of URLEncoder which is clean and it is working, actually I was following salesforce's documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/headers_calloptions.htm

Answer (score 2):

Need to have html encoding for >, <.

Please try below and see whether it works with &gt; instead of >

```
  private static final String created_date_compared = "2016-02-01T00:00:00.000+0000";

   String restURL;

    restURL = "/tooling/query/?q=Select+Id,DeveloperName,NamespacePrefix+From+CustomField+Where+LastModifiedDate+&gt;+="+ created_date_compared;
```